# How to find the dimension of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, fortran, dimension

I have a matrix that contains both character and reals and I want a program that reads this matrix (finds the dimensions by itself). Here is my code:

```
! A fortran95 program for G95
Program Project2nd
implicit none
character(len=40), allocatable :: a(:,:)
integer i,j,k,n,m,l,st
character(len=40) d
n=0; m=1; j=1;

open(10,file=&
 '/Users/dariakowsari/Documents/Physics/Programming/Fortran95-Projects/Project2nd/input.txt', &
   IOstat=st)

do while (st == 0)
   read(10,*,IOstat=st) d
   n=n+1
end do

st=0
do j=1,m
  do while (st == 0)
     allocate(a(1,m))
        read(10,*,IOstat=st) (a(1,j),j=1,m)
          m=m+1
         deallocate(a)
 end do

 print*, n,m


end
```

Here is my Matrix:

```
a   b   13   15.5   13.2
c   d   16   16.75  19
e   f   19.2 12.2   18.2
```

With this code I got (3,2) for the dimensions of my matrix.

Comment: your code only actually counts the three lines. you get a 2 for m only because m is initialized to 1 and gets incremented in the second loop regardless of the iostat error (which is  simply end of file).   A bit of an aside, but it is poor practice to specify iostat on your open statement and then do nothing to check the value.

Comment: What do you know about the contents of the file before you open it ?  Is it always composed of `n` (unknown) lines each having 2 (separate) single-character elements followed by 3 (numeric, real) elements ?

Comment: @High Performance Mark                                                                         we know that the matrix contains both characters and integer numbers.       it may have n columns that contains character and m columns integer.

Comment: If your matrix contains only characters and integers why do you show an example containing reals ?

Comment: @agentp                                                                                                             what do you mean by "regardless of the iostat error (which is simply end of file)"?                                                                                                                      actually the second loop will execute only once,the second time that loop execute st gets 1 though it must be 0!!!!!

Comment: I'm sorry I meant real numbers.

Comment: your first loop reaches the end of the file. (i guess you dont realise that read advances to the next line even though you only read one item)  All reads afterward will always give the the iostat end of file error.  The line `m=m+1` is executed the same whether you get an iostat error or not.

Comment: should i use rewind in order to make it read from first of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your example code which means it doesn't compile for me but after a few changes I managed to get a similar result to you. 
**Update: As noted by @francescalus in the comments to my other (now deleted) answer, that approach involved undefined behaviour and as such is not an appropriate solution. This arose from trying to read more elements from the file than were present.*)

Here's an alternative approach, which should avoid this undefined behaviour, but is probably pretty inefficient.

```
Program Project2nd
  implicit none
  character(len=40), allocatable :: a(:)
  integer, allocatable :: ind(:)
  integer, parameter :: maxElements = 100
  integer i,j,n,m,st
  character(len=40) d
  n=0;

  open(10,file='mat.txt',IOstat=st)
  !Find number of lines
  do while (st == 0)
     read(10,*,IOstat=st) d
     if(st ==0) n=n+1
  end do
  !Move back to the start of the file
  rewind(10)

  !Read all of the data
  do m=n,maxElements,n
     allocate(a(m))
     read(10,*,IOstat=st) a
     deallocate(a)
     rewind(10)
     if(st.ne.0) exit
  enddo
  m = m -n !Need to roll back m by one iteration to get the last which worked.
  if(mod(m,n).ne.0) then
     print*,"Error: Number of elements not divisible by number of rows."
     stop
  endif
  !Number of columns = n_elements/nrow
  m=m/n
  print*, n,m
end Program Project2nd
```

Essentially this uses the same code as you had for counting the number of lines, however note that you only want to increment n when the read was successful (i.e. st==0). Note we do not exit the whilst block as soon as st becomes non-zero, it is only once we reach the end of the whilst block. After that we need to rewind the file so that the next read starts at the start of the file.

In a previous comment you mentioned that you'd rather not have to specify `maxElement` if you really want to avoid this then replace the second `do` loop with something like

```
  st = 0 ; m = n
  do while (st==0)
     allocate(a(m))
     read(10,*,IOstat=st) a
     deallocate(a)
     rewind(10)
     if(st.ne.0) then
       m = m - n !Go back to value of m that worked            
       exit
     endif
     m=m+n
  enddo
```

Comment: are your two answers different enough to be seperate answers?  If you are simply modifying/improving an answer you should edit it instead of posting a new answer.  The two here look pretty much the same so you should delete the old one.

Comment: @agentp Thanks, I wasn't sure what was appropriate here, I've heard arguments against modifying an answer if it introduces a significant difference, for some definition of significant.

Comment: @roygivb thanks I just spotted that whilst editing! I think I should delete the original answer as it is incorrect. This version should (hopefully) be correct and I've edited to include the main points from the original post.

Comment: thank you so much @d_1999.                                                                                    your answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note the reason I switched to iterating in steps of `n` is that @SinaTehrani indicated they may be interested in some quite large matrices so I thought this optimisation (reducing the number of iterations by a factor `n`) was worth the additional complexity.

Answer (score 1):

here is how to do w/o rewinding.

```
  implicit none
  character(len=100) wholeline
  character(len=20), allocatable :: c(:)
  integer iline,io,ni,nums
  open(20,file='testin.dat')
  iline=0
  do while(.true.)
     read(20,'(a)',iostat=io)wholeline
     if(io.ne.0)exit
     iline=iline+1
     ni=lineitems(wholeline)
     allocate(c(ni))
     read(wholeline,*)c
     nums=ctnums(c)
     write(*,*)'line',iline,' contains ',ni,'items',nums,
 $        'are numbers'
     deallocate(c)
  enddo
  write(*,*)'total lines is ',iline
  contains

  integer function ctnums(c)
  ! count the number of items in a character array that are numbers
  ! this is a template,
  ! obviously you could assign the numbers to a real array here
  character(len=*), allocatable :: c(:)      
  real f
  integer i,io
  ctnums=0
  do i = 1,size(c)
     read(c(i),*,iostat=io)f
     if(io.eq.0)ctnums=ctnums+1
  enddo
  end function

  integer function lineitems(line)
  ! count the number of items in a space delimited string
  integer,parameter ::maxitems=100
  character(len=*) line
  character(len=80) :: c(maxitems)
  integer iline,io
  lineitems=0
  do iline=1,maxitems
     read(line,*,iostat=io)c(:iline)
     if(io.ne.0)return
     lineitems=iline
  enddo
  if(lineitems.eq.maxitems)write(*,*)'warning maxitems reached'
  end function
  end
```

output

```
line 1 contains 5 items 3 are numbers
line 2 contains 5 items 3 are numbers
total lines is 2
```